# No internet access from browser after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 and am having problems connecting to the internet from the browser. I have looked at/tried the following:

- Checked the network settings for my wired connection - everything looks fine, it is connected, IP details assigned by my DHCP server (router) all look correct
- Checked the Admin interface of my router, all looks correct. The IP address assigned to the Ubuntu box is listed
- Pinged my router from the Ubuntu box, successful HOWEVER it appears to query forever. It was up to 100 odd pings before I killed the process
- Pinged other machines on my local network, successful
- Pinged Google, 8.8.8.8 successful
- Ran a successful apt update

I have tried Firefox, Chromium and Chrome ALL of them display unable to load page messages. I have looked through all settings that I think make sense in the browser and can find nothing. I have looked at my VPN (NordVPN) and ensured that the kill switch is turned off - HELP!!! :=] Thanks for any assistance in advance...

Comment: It seems silly, but have you tried rebooting the machine? Also, (if you've tried it), does uninstalling your VPN and then rebooting fix it?

Comment: Before uninstalling the VPN can you on your phone maybe contact NordVPN and ask them if there is something you need to fix?

Comment: Are the homedirectories under `/home` ? Are the browsers installed via snap? Can you ping the nameserver (8.8.8.8) ? Can you add the exact message your browser shows to your question?

Comment: Try reinstalling Firefox as not a snap package. or a full reset of Firefox is required.